# Can StackAuth indicate whether a linked meta is in private / public beta?

Tags: feature-request, stackauth

Currently, StackAuth returns:

```
state: linked_meta
```

...regardless of the state of the parent site.

This makes my logic quite complicated as then I have to match it up with its parent site to find its state.

Can we change it to:

```
state: linked_meta_private_beta
state: linked_meta_public_beta
```

** Maybe this can be a v1.1 feature?*

Answer (score 1):

How hard is it to remove "meta." from the `api_endpoint` and then iterate through the list of about a dozen sites you got already to find the one with a matching host name?  In Objective-C, which is generally considered a verbose language, it takes maybe a dozen lines or so to be really thorough and catch corner cases and whatnot...

For reference, [here's how I retrieve it](http://github.com/davedelong/StackKit/blob/master/Classes/SKSite.m#L191).

Comment: Sorry, but I've never touched Objective-C before in my life :) I'm just asking for something a little more intuitive.